# Requerying other bindings when another binding changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

**tl;dr:**
What is the 'correct' way to requery bindings when another binding has changed?

**Context:**
I'm developing an MVVM application that looks and behaves similar to MS Access. (Ribbon + tabbed interface).

Basically, when a certain tab (viewmodel) is selected, I need certain contextual tabs to be displayed. I have a number of properties in my view model which determine if a set of contexual tabs is visible or not. As an example. I'd want the contextual tabs for ViewModel1 to show, when ViewModel1 is the 'selected' viewmodel, so I have this property in my view model.

```
public bool ViewModel1Active
{
    get { return (selectedWorkspace is ViewModel1); }
    set { Set(ref viewModel1Active, value); }
}
```

I also have a separate property which is bound to the selected view model:

```
public WorkspaceViewModel SelectedWorkspace
{
    get { return selectedWorkspace; }
    set { Set(ref selectedWorkspace, value); }
}
```

My theory is that when the set accessor is called on `SelectedWorkspace`, I requery all of the bindings for the contextual tabs:

```
public WorkspaceViewModel SelectedWorkspace
{
    get { return selectedWorkspace; }
    set { Set(ref selectedWorkspace, value); RefreshContextualTabs(); }
}

void RefreshContextualTabs()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("ViewModel1IsActive");
    RaisePropertyChanged("ViewModel2IsActive");
   // etc.
}
```

Which should show the correct set of tabs when the viewmodel is selected

Is there a better way to approach this?

Libraries being used: MVVMLight and FluentRibbon

Comment: as a side-note, and if I remember correctly: PropertyChanged.Fody detects such dependencies and adds automatic triggering of all connected properties ... I prefer weaving over manually coding anyway ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, is [this](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) what you're talking about?

Comment: ? there's something missing I guess. Anyway, you can find a rough overview at https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/blob/master/README.md